# Segmentation fault only in realease configuration when manipulating strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

below is the function *fast_integer_output* that converts *input_integer* from base 2 into *output_base*.

```
my_str* fast_integer_output(bigint* input_integer, int output_base)
{
    bigint** integer_to_binary_array = create_integer_to_binary_array();
    bigint* base = integer_to_binary_array[output_base];
    my_str* result = 0;

    if(less_than(input_integer, base))
    {
        char* p_char = (char*) get_memory(sizeof(char));
        p_char[0] = int_to_char(*(input_integer->number));

        result = create_string(p_char, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        long k = find_k(input_integer, base);
        bigint* base_to_k = power(base, k);

        bigint* quotient;
        bigint* remainder;

        divide(input_integer, base_to_k, &quotient, &remainder);
        delete_bigint(&base_to_k);

        my_str* low = fast_integer_output(remainder, output_base);
        delete_bigint(&remainder);

        my_str* high = fast_integer_output(quotient, output_base);
        delete_bigint(&quotient);

        result = concatenate(low,  k - low->length, high);

        delete_string(&low);
        delete_string(&high);
    }

    release_integer_to_binary_array(integer_to_binary_array);
    return result;
}
```

Here are *bigint* and *my_str* structs and *create_string* function (`bitarray` is just a pointer to `long`)

```
my_str* create_string(char* c_str, long length)
{
    my_str* str = (my_str*) get_memory(sizeof(my_str));
    str->c_str = c_str;
    str->length = length;
}

typedef struct
{
    char*   c_str;
    long    length;  // logical
} my_str;

typedef struct
{
    bitarray*   number;
    long        length;  // logical
    long        size;    // physical
} bigint;
```

And this functions take care of memory management. Right now they are just wrapping functions to *free* and *malloc* but I would like to implement some kind of memory pool if it will be slow in operation.

```
void init_memory(void* memory, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char* tmp = (unsigned char*) memory;
    unsigned char c = 0;

    while (size > 0)
    {
        *tmp = c;
        tmp++;
        size--;
    }
}

void* get_memory(size_t size)
{
    void* memory = malloc(size);
    init_memory(memory, size);
    return memory;
}

void release_memory(void** memory)
{
    free(*memory);
    *memory = 0;
}
```

Problem is that everything runs fine on debug configuration, but on release configuration the function *fast_integer_output* fails on the line :

```
result = concatenate(low,  k - low->length, high);
```

The problem is that

```
my_str* low = fast_integer_output(remainder, output_base);
```

which returns from this piece of code

```
if(less_than(input_integer, base))
{
    char* p_char = (char*) get_memory(sizeof(char));
    p_char[0] = int_to_char(*(input_integer->number));

    result = create_string(p_char, 1);
}
```

returns trash and thus it fails on segmentation fault.

I had the same problem with this code:

```
QString buffer; // function parameter in real code
instance_data_t data = {(unsigned char*) buffer.toStdString().c_str(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, cur_state};
```

but I managed to get it working by changing it into following:

```
unsigned char c_buffer[1024];
memset(c_buffer, '\0', sizeof(c_buffer));
strcpy((char *) c_buffer, buffer.toStdString().c_str());

instance_data_t data = {c_buffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, cur_state};
```

Important note is that I cannot use any other functions than *write*, *read*, malloc and *free* (so no strcpy, above code is from test which I will not deliver)

This is not a homework, it is an assignment for a job (I would like to get).

I've searched and read about 15-20 questions, so I will not list them all, but the problem is that mostly, if the question is not very specific, the segmentation fault is not because of string manipulation and if it is, then it is mostly because of index out of bounds.

Comment: Why don't you run your program within valgrind ?

Comment: [Please provide a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve9). For now there's not a lot to say except that the code overall looks very fishy. And it is C++ in disguise, not C, right?

Comment: C-"string" ought to be `0`-terminated.

Comment: @EOF I don't think so, can you explain why ?

Comment: @EOF sizeof(my_str) will return the size of the my_str structure, not the size of a pointer. The function will then allocate the right amount of memory

Comment: @Tezirg: You're right, sorry. The glaring error in `create_string()` is obviously the lack of a `return`-statement.

Comment: @EOF Ohhhh good catch, that's the solution of this thread here. I will add it to my answer if you don't mind

Comment: @Tezirg omg guys, you are right! Such a shame, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your allocated string is not null ('\0') terminated.

I would do it this way :

```
  char* p_char = (char*) get_memory(sizeof(char) * 2);

  p_char[0] = int_to_char(*(input_integer->number));
  p_char[1] = 0;

  result = create_string(p_char, 1);
```

As EOF pointed out (see comments),
The create_string function as no return statement.
Thus, garbage is indeed returned.

```
my_str* create_string(char* c_str, long length)
{
    my_str* str = (my_str*) get_memory(sizeof(my_str));
    str->c_str = c_str;
    str->length = length;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @alk yes because a sizeof(char) = 1. However this is error prone. It is good practice to multiply the the length by the sizeof(type) to allocate an array.